# Mirth: How to send to a destination multiple times

Tags: mirth

I would like to read a HL7 message containing multiple orders (ORC segments). My destination is a web service sender which can only handle one order at a time.

How can I iterate through the input HL7 message and send to a destination each time?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You may create another channel that communicates with your web-service and route the ORC portion to that channel.

For additional information you may read the "Unofficial Mirth Connect Developer's Guide" available at mirthconnect.shamilpublishing.com

(Disclaimer: I'm the author of this guide so any comments or suggestions are welcome.)

Comment: Hi and thanks so much for the feedback. I may not understand correctly but I cannot see how the other channel can know which ORC to send. If my input contains 4 ORC segments then my source connector needs to route a message to the web service sender channel 4 times (4 times to the destination).

Comment: There are several ways of doing this. First way is to create four destinations each of which deletes unnecessary ORC segment before passing the message to the web service.  Another way is to create a copy of the original message without ORC segments, loop through all ORCs of the original message, add the ORC segment to the copy and rout the copy to another channel. There may other ways of achieving same result. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As is stated above there are several ways to do it.

I normally did this in a JavaScript transformer step.  I basically built a small state engine that would iterate over the incoming (raw) message by splitting the incoming message on '\r' characters.  It would then build the outbound message as a string by identifying the "header" section (part that does not change) and storing that in a string, say Header, and the order section (the part that does change) as another string, say Order, and the concatenating them together when I reach the next order or the end of the string and sending them to another channel with

`router.routeMessage('channelName', Header + '\r' + Order);`